# Как создать возможность смены темы приложения

Tags: android

Как создать возможность смены темы приложения в ночной режим. К примеру как в moonreader 
https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.flyersoft.moonreader&hl=en

Заранее буду благодарен

Comment: super.setTheme( " Путь к вашей теме "); - в onCreate(), перед setContentView();

Comment: @Gin Tasan , А к примеру если у меня есть картинки, каким образом можно будет их менять, только кодом? И может вы знаете статьи на эту темя для чайных чайников. Заранее спасибо за ответ.

Comment: У ImageView image.setImageResource(Ваш путь к картинке);  Куча инфы - http://developer.alexanderklimov.ru/android/views/imageview.php